# Rearrange master page elements without custom master page

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, custom-masterpage, branding

We're migrating from on-prem to O365 and I'm really trying to not use customer masterpages anymore however we have one little requirement, namely to move the site title to above the breadcrumb/navigation as opposed to seattle.master where the site title is below the global navigation. I can take a copy of seattle and rearrange the elements but rather not to, is there a good alternative way to achieve the requirement in the attached image?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your **custom css** to align UI as per your
    requirement

**To add a custom CSS to a site**

1. Upload the CSS file to the Site Assets or to another location on
   your SharePoint site.
2. Click on the settings gear and select Site settings.
3. In the Look and Feel group, click on the link 'Master page'.
4. Expand 'Alternate CSS URL'.
5. Select the 'Specify a CSS file' option and browse to the location
   where you uploaded your CSS file.
6. Check the box for subsite inheritance if you want all subsites to
   use the CSS file.
7. Click OK.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Anil, this would require to set some elements with position: absolute though which I also try to avoid?